# Confused with multiple dimension dictionaries

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary

I got this method which returns a multi-dimensional dictionary.

```
def get_apps():
    menu_one = {
        'name': 'Apps group one',
        'menu_one_app_one': {
            'name': 'app one!',
            'icon': 'fa-rocket',
            'url': '/Url'
        },
        'menu_one_app_two': {
            'name': 'app two!',
            'icon': 'fa-user',
            'url': '/Url2'
        }
    },
    menu_two = {
        'name': 'Apps group two',
        'menu_two_app_one': {
            'name': 'app three!',
            'icon': 'fa-clipboard',
            'url': '/Url3'
        },
        'menu_two_app_two': {
            'name': 'app four!',
            'icon': 'fa-users',
            'url': '/Url4'
        }
    }
    return menu_one, menu_two
```

So in my Django view I'm calling the method `get_apps()` in order to get the apps with their attributes and show them on different groups like this:

```
def my_django_view(request):
    apps = get_apps()
    return render(request, "apps.html", {'apps': apps})
```

And the idea is to display them by group in my template like this:

```
{% for menu in apps %} <!-- this is ok! -->
    <div class="breadcrumb">        
        <h1>{{ menu.name }}</h1>
        {% for app in menu %} <!-- here is the part where I am wrong -->
            <a href="{{ app.url }}"
               data-toggle="tooltip"
               title="{{ app.name }}">
                <i class="fa {{ app.icon }}"></i>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I know what is wrong thanks to django since it's saying 'str' has no attr 'name', of course, since it is a dictionary. But then, how can I loop over this? I found other examples but none of them where useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: You have a trailing comma in `menu_one`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through a dictionary using `items`.  generally, you want to do something like this:

1. loop through the separate menus
2. loop through each of the sub menus in each menu

Because of (2), we'd be better served by defining each menu with an array:

```
    menu_one = {
        'name': 'Apps group one',
        'menus': [{
            'name': 'app one!',
            'icon': 'fa-rocket',
            'url': '/Url'
        }, {
            'name': 'app two!',
            'icon': 'fa-user',
            'url': '/Url2'
        }],
    }
```

Now that our menus are an array, it's much easier to use them:

```
{% for menu in apps %} <!-- this is ok! -->
    <div class="breadcrumb">        
        <h1>{{ menu.name }}</h1>
        {% for app in menu.menus %} 
            <a href="{{ app.url }}"
               data-toggle="tooltip"
               title="{{ app.name }}">
                <i class="fa {{ app.icon }}"></i>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```